# Fitting multidimensional data

Tags: fitting

Suppose i have some function

```
G[n_,B_,d_] = ....
```

to fit this function i need to collect the data first. However at first i dont understand how to format the data what i have done is:

```
 data = Table[G[n_,B_,d_],{n,100},{d,5},{B,0.01,1,0.01}]
```

Now suppose i want to fit the following function:

```
 F[n_,B_,d_,a_,b_,c_,d_] = a + b Tanh[c*B^(e*d)*n^(f)]
```

I tried to compute this by:

```
 FindFit[data, a + b Tanh[c*B^(e*d)*n^(f)],{a,b,c,e,f},{n,B,d}]
```

getting the error that my data is not rectangular, furthermore i think i am formatting in the wrong way anyone got a tip for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[model];
model[n_, B_, d_, a_, b_, c_] := a + b Tanh[B^d c n]

data = With[
   {
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3
    },
   Flatten[
    Table[
     N[{n, d, B, model[n, B, d, a, b, c] + RandomReal[0.1]}]
     , {n, 100}
     , {B, 0.01, 1, 0.01}
     , {d, 5}
     ], 2]
   ];
```

This is how your data should look like. A single list with elements `{ni,Bi,di, measuredvalue}`

```
Short[data]
(* {{1.,1.,0.01,1.13965},<<49998>>,{100.,5.,1.,3.06851}} *)

FindFit[data, model[n, B, d, a, b, c], {a, b, c}, {n, d, B}]
(* {a -> 1.04984, b -> 1.99999, c -> 2.99911} *)
```

A good hint is to read the documentation for [`FindFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html)

[image]

Comment: thanks i just jumped to the examples never saw that tab :D

Answer (score 1):

I think your "data" is wrong format. You might want to try this

```
data=Table[{n,b,d,G[n,B,d]},{n,100},{d,5},{B,0.01,1,0.01}]
```

**Example**

Because I could able to fit multi-dimensional data

```
param = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 6}];
vari = {x^2, y^2, z^2, x y, x z, y z};
G[x_, y_, z_] := Evaluate[param.vari]
estim = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6};
data = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, z, G[x, y, z]}, {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 
     0.1}, {z, -1, 1, 0.1}], 2];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, estim.vari, estim, {x, y, z}];
```

and i got

```
{estim, param, nlm["BestFitParameters"][[All, 2]]} // TableForm

   a1          a2          a3          a4           a5         a6
0.460446    0.259803    0.346077    0.767826    0.0984281   0.685461
0.460446    0.259803    0.346077    0.767826    0.0984281   0.685461
```

Comment: tried this i get this error:

FindFit::fitd: First argument {<<1>>} in FindFit is not a list or a rectangular array.

Comment: my command is FindFit[data, a + b Tanh[c*B^(e*d)*n^(f)], {a, b, c, e, f}, {n, d, B}]

Comment: I think @rhermans answers the question! :D